# ValueError in df.transform(lambda x: 0 if (x == 0) else (-np.log(-x) if x < 0 else np.log(x)))

Tags: python, pandas

Does anybody know how to fix this?

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(3), 'B': range(1, 4)})
>>> df
   A  B
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  2  3
>>> df.transform(lambda x: 0 if (x == 0) else (-np.log(-x) if x < 0 else np.log(x)))
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index A')
```

Answer (score 1):

`x==0` returns a series of `True` and `False`. For example, `df['A'] == 0` returns a `pd.Series` with `[True, False, False]` values. What is `if pd.Series([True, False, False])` supposed to mean? It doesn't make sense, and that's why it is ambiguous.

Also, `apply` does not make use of vectorization, so avoid it.

Use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) instead

```
df = np.select([df==0, df > 0, df < 0], [0, np.log(df), -np.log(-df)])
```

If you want to investigate deeper the error *ValueError: 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()*, just google it. [There are tons of stackoverflow posts about it](https://www.google.com/search?q=ValueError%3A%20%27The%20truth%20value%20of%20a%20Series%20is%20ambiguous.%20Use%20a.empty%2C%20a.bool()%E2%80%A6&oq=ValueError%3A%20%27The%20truth%20value%20of%20a%20Series%20is%20ambiguous.%20Use%20a.empty%2C%20a.bool()%E2%80%A6&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.264j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: So, there is no way to implement it through transform function?

Comment: @happyastronaut there is a way, but `transform` is slow and not recommended.